# Error when getting values from json to data table

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, datatable, material-ui

I created an app in React and Flask that loads some json info into a data table.
In the console.log I can see it but I didn`t manage to put it in the data table.
I am using Material-UI and React

This is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';




function App() {

 const columns = [
{ field: 'cnp', headerName: 'CNP', width: 130 },
{ field: 'cui', headerName: 'CUI', width: 130 },
{ field: 'mesaje', headerName: 'Mesaje', width: 130 },
{ field: 'serial', headerName: 'Serial',width: 130,},
{ field: 'titlu', headerName: 'Titlu', width: 130,},
];



useEffect(() => {
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/formular',{
headers : { 
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
}

}).then(response =>
response.json().then(data =>{
console.log(data);

})
);
},[]);

const rows = [
{ id: 1, cnp: .data.cui, cui: data.cui, mesaje: data.mesaje, serial: data.serial, titlu: data.titlu 
},

];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
return <div className="App">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  <h1>Lista mesaje</h1>
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
  refresh
</Button>
<br></br>

<div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
  
  </div>;

}

export default App;
```

When I run the app the data loads in the console I can see the info but it doesn t load in the data-table.
It`s my first time using React. The error is:

```
 ./src/App.js
 Line 38:19:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

 36 | 
 37 |   const rows = [
 > 38 |     { id: 1, cnp: .data.cui, cui: data.cui, mesaje: data.mesaje, serial: data.serial, titlu: 
 data.titlu },
    |                   ^
 39 | 
 40 |   ];
 41 |
```

Comment: Looks like `cnp: .data.cui` should be `cnp: data.cui`. What does the data look like that's being returned from your API call?

Comment: I deleted the dot before data and now it gives me this error: ./src/App.js
  Line 38:19:  'data' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 38:34:  'data' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 38:52:  'data' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 38:73:  'data' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 38:93:  'data' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: It is because `data` is only available in the scope of the promise you're writing. Try assigning `data` value to another variable which is in the same scope or above of `rows`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
const rows = [
{ id: 1, cnp: .data.cui, cui: data.cui, mesaje: data.mesaje, serial: data.serial, titlu: data.titlu 
},
```

You have added,

```
cnp: .data.cui
```

This is causing the issue. I believe it should be,

```
cnp: data.cui
```

Note: The extra `.`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having issues with `data` not being defined while trying to access it (that's assuming you've resolved the invalid syntax of `.data.cui`).

Assuming it is an issue with `data` being undefined (because it's not in scope when trying to access it) you could try something like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

function App() {
  const columns = [
    { field: "cnp", headerName: "CNP", width: 130 },
    { field: "cui", headerName: "CUI", width: 130 },
    { field: "mesaje", headerName: "Mesaje", width: 130 },
    { field: "serial", headerName: "Serial", width: 130 },
    { field: "titlu", headerName: "Titlu", width: 130 },
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const rawData = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/formular", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      });
      const fetchedData = await rawData.json();
      setData(fetchedData);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const rows = [
    {
      id: 1,
      cnp: data?.cui,
      cui: data?.cui,
      mesaje: data?.mesaje,
      serial: data?.serial,
      titlu: data?.titlu,
    },
  ];
}
```

Note that this *does not* perform any error handling, however as a first pass can hopefully get you going!